How to use PHP in my React project to send an email from a form
I'm new to React and I'm having a problem using a form in React (in component called "Home").
What I want to do is to have a form with a button that sends the information to a specific email. But when I execute the page and click on the button Submit what I get is an "Cannot POST /send-email.php".
My React component is the following:
`function Home(){

return(
    <div>
        <section id="homeMail">
            <form method="post" action="send-email.php">
                <label forHTML="name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required></input>

                <label forHTML="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required></input>
                
                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required></input>

                <label forHTML="message">Contact us:</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>

                <button>Send</button>
            
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
)
}

export default Home;`

And the PHP code of send-email.php is the following:
`<?php

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail -> SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;

$mail -> isSMTP();
$mail -> SMTPAuth = true;

$mail -> Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail -> SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail -> Port = 587;

$mail -> Username = "specific@email.com"
$mail -> Password = "correctpassword";

$mail -> setFrom($email, $name);
$mail -> addAddress("specific@email.com", "Recipient");

$mail -> Subject = $subject;
$mail -> Body = $message;

$mail -> send();

header("Location: index.html")`

I have already tried changing de locations of my send-email.php file, putting it in the same folder as the Home React component and in the "public" folder of the React project, none of them worked. I have also seen various Stack Overflow posts but didn't anything on React and asked ChatGPT but couldn't handle my problem.

Do you have PHP installed?

Is this a PHP problem or a React problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?
